# Can magna be a noun or an adverb?

Tags: classical-latin

In this passage from Ars Poetica we find:

Ī́ncēptī́s grăuĭbū́s plērū́mque‿ēt mā́gnă prŏfḗssis

Pū́rpŭrĕū́s, lātḗ quī splḗndĕăt, ū́nŭs ĕt ā́lter

Ā́dsŭĭtū́r pānnū́s

I can't figure out if 'magna' is an adverb or a noun or if it is an adjective, which the OLD says it is, then what does it modify.  In the LASLA database it says that 'magna' is a plural accusative modifying a neuter noun.  I don't see any other nouns in this sentence which are plural accusative neuter.  Here's the LASLA breakdown where the first column is the lemma, the second is the part of speech and the third is inflected form:

(The C in the part of speech pCd means any gender, though LASLA does not always get the gender right)

inceptum pNd                       **inceptīs**
grauis pCd                            **gravibus**
plerumque d                         **plerumque**_
et2 d                                    **et**
magnus pna                          *magna*
profiteor pr.ac.pCd               **professis**_
purpureus smn                      *purpureus*
late d                                   *late*
qui1 smn                              **quī**
splendeo 3.pr.sj.ac                **splendeat**
unus m                                 *unus*
et2 d                                    **et**
alter smn                              *alter*
assuo 3.pr.in.pa                     *adsuitur*
pannus sMn                          **pannus**

The Buckley, I think, translation has it as:

In pompous introductions, and such as promise a great deal, it generally happens that one or two verses of purple patch-work, that may make a great show, are tagged on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a substantive neuter plural adjective, and is the object of *professis*: "promising great (things)".

Comment: thnx, I appreciate that.